# how to modify the path with hook_menu_local_actions_alter

Tags: 8, hooks

when I add the hook_local_actions_alter to my module, I can see that the node.add.page link shows up on certain pages as below.  how can I modify this so that this also show up on a different path in addition to the "admin/content" link it already shows up on ?  I want it to also show up on "admin/owncontent" .

[node.add_page] => Array
            (
                [id] => node.add_page
                [title] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup Object
                    (
                        [string:protected] => Add content
                        [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
                        [options:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

```
                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                    [arguments:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [weight] => 
            [route_name] => node.add_page
            [route_parameters] => Array
                (
                )

            [options] => Array
                (
                )

            [appears_on] => Array
                (
                    [0] => system.admin_content
                )

            [class] => Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalActionDefault
            [provider] => node
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Local actions and tasks (and menu links) don't apply to paths, they apply to routes.

For local actions to appear somewhere, you put them in the appears_on list, as you can see in your dump for the system.admin_content route. Just add your own route name there.

If you don't know your route name (e.g., because it is a view or otherwise dynamically defined page), you can look it up for example with the WebProfiler module that's part of [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel). Or you look in the `router` table.

Note that having hardcoded definitions on something like a view is a bit problematic, if the view is deleted or renamed, the route name will change and your code will break. That's probably OK for custom modules as you can assume that nobody will do that. One way to work around that is to specify a dummy route with the same path in a routing.yml file, views will see that and use the same route name.

Comment: can you explain how to specify a dummy route as you say here ?